# Cannot bind `ref` when using `v-for`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to create polygons inside `<svg>...</svg>` so I used `v-for` like this:

```
<polygon v-for="id in polygonArr" :key="id" :ref="id" points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459" />
```

and in `polygonArr` is

```
data() {
  return {
    ...
    polygonArr: [1, 2, 5],
    ...
  }
},
```

But when I run it and check with the inspector tool, it shows like this

```
...
<polygon data-v-5567ea9e="" points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459"></polygon>
<polygon data-v-5567ea9e="" points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459"></polygon>
<polygon data-v-5567ea9e="" points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459"></polygon>
...
```

as you can see, `:ref="..."` isn't present in the output.

I tried changing `:ref="i"` to `:refx="i"` and it works perfectly as:

```
<polygon data-v-5567ea9e="" refx="1" points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459"></polygon>
<polygon data-v-5567ea9e="" refx="2" points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459"></polygon>
<polygon data-v-5567ea9e="" refx="5" points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459"></polygon>
```

Why is it like this? And how should I do to solve this? Other attributes such as `title`, etc. seem to work fine.

Comment: Why do you need the `ref` attribute? I can't see it as a legal attribute on the mozilla docs for SVG, and as @Sergeon stated in his answer, `ref` is a used internally by Vue so it does not appear in the DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute

Comment: @Hammerbot I need `ref` for Vue since it cannot use `document.getElementById()` directly, it requires `ref` to refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ref` is used internally by Vue components to reference its children. In the Vue component that is rendering your `<polygon>`'s, you can access that ref via `this.$refs`. However, it won't show up in the HTML.

Not sure right now, but you may be able to inspect the `ref` attribute in the [vue developer tools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) however.